# Azure AD External Identity using SAML without invitation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to setup Azure AD integration with our partner identities. I have few providers that I need to support and they support SAML and WS-Fed. I am trying to use Azure AD External Identities to add these providers to my Azure AD tenant.

However, reading through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation), it seems like SAML integrations are invitation based.

I want users to be able to login without an invitation. How can I do this with Azure AD?

Here are my needs:

1. After adding the external idp, users should be able to login using their own credentails via their idp. No additional information needed to use an app.
2. I should be able to grant them access to custom apps (mandatory) and azure resources (optional)
3. Choose what idp's are allowed per app? (if possible)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** After adding the external idp, users should be able to login using their own credentials via their idp. No additional information needed to use an app.

**Answer:**
We can implement Guest users redemption using direct link or a common endpoint instead of email invitation. A guest user clicks the app link, reviews and accepts the privacy terms, and then seamlessly accesses the app.

***Using Common endpoint :*** Guest users can now sign in to your multi-tenant or Microsoft first-party apps through a common endpoint (URL), for example https://myapps.microsoft.com. Previously, a common URL would redirect a guest user to their home tenant instead of your resource tenant for authentication, so a tenant-specific link was required (for example https://myapps.microsoft.com/?tenantid=). Now the guest user can go to the application's common URL, choose Sign-in options, and then select Sign in to an organization. The user then types the name of your organization.

***Using Direct Link:*** As an alternative to the invitation email or an application's common URL, you can give a guest a direct link to your app or portal. You first need to add the guest user to your directory via the Azure Portal or Powershell Then you can use any of the customizable ways to deploy applications to users, including direct sign-on links. When a guest uses a direct link instead of the invitation email, they’ll still be guided through the first-time consent experience.

**Reference:**

[Add B2B guests without an invitation link or email - Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-user-without-invite)

[Invitation redemption in B2B collaboration - Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/redemption-experience)

**Question 2 :** I should be able to grant them access to custom apps (mandatory) and azure resources (optional)

**Answer:** Add the Users as Guest to Azure active Directory but by default they will be sent an invitation even if they don’t open it you can assign an app in your enterprise application for them to use .

Most federated applications that support SAML 2.0, WS-Federation, or OpenID connect also support the ability for users to start at the application, and then get signed in through Azure AD either by automatic redirection or by clicking on a link to sign in. This is known as service provider-initiated sign-on, and most federated applications in the Azure AD application gallery

**Reference:**

[End-user experiences for applications - Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/end-user-experiences#direct-sign-on-links)

[Quickstart: Add guest users in the Azure portal - Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal#assign-an-app-to-the-guest-user)

To Provide the Guest user access to azure resources you can manually [add a role to the users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current).

**Question 3:** Choose what idp's are allowed per app?

**Answer:** Create different user flows and add desired IDPs to the user flows and then assign applications registered in Azure AD to the user flows depending on which IDPs are needed for given application.

**Reference:**

[Add a self-service sign-up user flow - Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow#enable-self-service-sign-up-for-your-tenant)

**Question 4:** I added Okta as an External Identity using SAML in my Azure AD. Created an "App Registration" as multi-tenant. But I am getting this error.

> AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx' from identity provider 'http://www.okta.com/xxxxx' does not exist in tenant '' and cannot access the application '0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'(Microsoft App Access Panel) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

**Solution:** Please Ensure User is added to one of the Partner Admin Groups i.e. AdminAgents in the Partner tenant.

**Reference:**

[Manage Auth access for cloud solution providers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-cloudsolutionprovider)

**Question 5:** Steps for setting self service signup for an application.

**Test Scenario in my Lab**

> - Azure AD with an application registered in application registrations blade.
> - Another AD tenant with users.

[image]

**Step 1:** In the above external identities collaboration settings please make sure to have `enable guest user self service` enabled.

If it is not enabled then you can’t create a self service flow and you will get the below error when a user from other tenant is trying to access the app.

[image]

**Step 2:** Create a user flow by going to the user flow blade and creating a new flow.

[image]

[image]

**Step 3:** After you have created the user flow , click on the User flow and go to application blade and click add application.

[image]

Now search for the application you want to provide the self service signup to and click on select and you will have now enable the self service sign up for users when they try to access your application.

[image]

**Output:**

Once the above settings are done you can access the url to your app. Provide the user of the different ad tenant and you will get output as below .Click on create a new one .

[image]
[image]

Once the user from other AD tenant have accepted it they are successfully registered as guest users in your tenant.

[image]

If they accept the above then they will be able to access the app from now as a guest.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed response. I have tried this. I added Okta as an External Identity using SAML in my Azure AD. Created an "App Registration" as multi-tenant. But I am getting this error.  `AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx' from identity provider 'http://www.okta.com/xxxxx' does not exist in tenant '<my tenant>' and cannot access the application '0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'(Microsoft App Access Panel) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.`

Comment: I am getting above error when acessing https://myapps.microsoft.com/?tenantid=<mytenantid> or when accessing my app url directly or create an app using "Non-Gallery Enterprise App"

Comment: @user3731783, i have added the above query and solution as question 4 in the answer..

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think what you mentioned for question 4 applies to me. If I add that user as Guest User in my tenant everything works fine and I do not want to have that step. It should behave like B2C where a user is created automatically if the user doesn't exist.

Comment: Hello @user3731783, for automating the signup process if the user is not a part of the tenant, then we can use the self service signup user flow which is mentioned in question 3 as it mentions "For applications you build, you can create user flows that allow a user to sign up for an app and create a new guest account.".

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought. But SAML idp I added is not visible to select when adding a new user flow

Comment: I tried creating flow with a SAML idp , I faced the same issue. I could find that we cannot currently add any SAML idp in flow for self service sign up only Microsoft and other supported idp that are showing on the page . So for now we ha e to manually add the users as guest. I referred https://serverfault.com/questions/1062333/aadsts50107-requested-federation-realm-object-does-not-exist-when-integrating/1062334#1062334

Comment: +1 ,If we consider the above then @AnsumanBal-MT your answer is helpful. Thank you for the detailed answer..

Comment: To summarize, if we want to use anything other than Google, Facebook or default provider ( Azure AD, Microsoft Account) we have to add users up front. Hopefully Microsoft will add SAML idp support for user flows soon. This is very restrictive considering  Azure AD mainly used by enterprises and many of then prefer SAML providers compared to Google/Facebook.

Comment: I agree to your point @user3731783 , we can provide feedback for feature in azure active directory here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT This is getting more confusing day by day. Self service is not working for with another Azure AD tenant too. I tried using myapps.microsoft.com?tenantid=<> url and I am getting same message, `user does not exist in tenant`. I do not have a common URL for app as this is registered using App Registration blade. Any advise?

Comment: Hello @user3731783, may I know the IDP you are using now ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT For my comment, my app is using one Azure AD tenant and user is another Azure AD tenant.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT To summarize and add more context, as mentioned in the questions, Azure AD is my source. All apps are going to use AzureAD and I want to add other partners to my tenant. We already concluded that accounts that belong External Identities added via SAML will not work with out adding those accounts to Azure AD first. Now, I am trying with users in another Azure AD and it is also not working.

Comment: Hello @user3731783, I created a test environment as per your scenario and configured my self service sign up for users in other tenant and it worked for me .. i have added the steps for that in the answer as Question 5 .. Can you please try it out and revert back if its working ..

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I really appreciate the effort you are putting into writing details answers, Thank you. I tried this and its working, I stopped as soon as it said Create new account.  Couple of confusions though, when I am creating an account in the password entry screen its showing background image of the current tenant (application tenant) not the bg image of my actual tenant for which this account belongs to. Also, in the user details, identityissuer is also the app tenant, which makes sense but I dont see the actual tenant of the external user anywhere

Comment: @user3731783, great to hear that it's working now . And about the background image,it will show the app tenant image as the app is registered there and we are signing up for the app tenant guest user. And same is  for the identity issuer as well .